# Adding values to end of pandas data frame from beginning of data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I have a pandas data frame that looks something like this:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 3
1 4 5 6
2 7 8 9
```

And I would like to add row 0 to the end of the data frame and to get a new data frame that looks like this:

```
  A B C
0 1 2 3
1 4 5 6
2 7 8 9
3 1 2 3
```

What can I do in pandas to do this?

Comment: `df.append(df.iloc[0])`?

Comment: `df.loc[len(df)] = df.iloc[0]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try:

```
df = df.append(df.iloc[0], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are inserting data from a list, this might help -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame( [ [1,2,3], [2,5,7], [7,8,9]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

print(df)
df.loc[-1] = [1,2,3] # list you want to insert
df.index = df.index + 1  # shifting index
df = df.sort_index()  # sorting by index
print(df)
```